# How to get user name from another table in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Hello I want to get user names on my reply table, but there its shows me only user id, when I type $reply->user_id->name it shows me that error: "Attempt to read property "name" on int".

How can I fix it ?

there are my codes:

***Ticket Model***

```
public function replies() {

    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    
}
```

***Reply Model***

```
 public function tickets() {

        return $this->belongsTo(Tickets::class);
    }
```

***Tickets Controller***

```
 public function show($id) {


       $user = Auth::user();
       
        $tickets = Tickets::with('companies')->get();

        $ticketscomp = Companies::with('tickets')->get();

        $severities = Severities::with('tickets')->get();

        $users = User::with('tickets')->get();

        //$replies = DB::table('replies')->where('ticket_id', $id)->get();

        
        // $articles = Reply::where('user_id', $id)->with('User')->get();

    
       $ticketspage = Tickets::with('severities')->with('companies')->with('user')->with('replies')->findOrFail($id);
 
      
        return view('tickets.ticket', compact('ticketspage'))->
        with(['tickets'=> $tickets])->
        with(['ticketscomp'=>$ticketscomp])->
        with(['severities'=>$severities])->
        with(['ticketspage'=>$ticketspage])->
        with(['replies'=>$replies]);
 
         //dd($reply_author->toArray());
        
    }
```

***Blade***

```
  @foreach ($replies as $reply)

            <div class="NjBSH">
                <div id="AuthorAndDate-1">
                    
                    <span class="author">{{ $reply->user_id->name }}</span>
                    
                    <span class="date"><span style="color: rgb(32, 33, 36);">{{ $reply->created_at }}</span><br></span>
                </div>
                <div class="kmSodw">
                    <span>{{ $reply->text }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        
        @endforeach
```

Text, Created at showing also $reply->user_id but not this $reply->user_id->name.

Comment: can you post the relationship between `Reply` and `User`? also, learn the difference between `Eloquent` and `QueryBuilder`.

Comment: I dont have it.

Comment: Well if I do User Belongs to and Reply hasmany it will be fixed?

Comment: so, `Reply` is not related to `User` in any way?

Comment: yes I dont have relationship between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a complete solution using ELOQUENT:

**Ticket Model**

```
public function replies() {
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);    
}
```

**Reply Model**

```
public function ticket() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Tickets Controller:**

```
public function show(Ticket $ticket) {  
    //Load all of the ticket relationships that we will be using
    $ticket->load('replies.articles', 'replies.user', 'companies', 'severities');
    
    //Assign the loaded ticket companies
    $companies = $ticket->companies;
    
    //Assign the loaded ticket severities
    $severities = $ticket->severities;
    
    //Assign the loaded ticket replies
    $replies = $ticket->replies;
    
    /* 
        You can acess the replies -> articles && user in a foreach loop, in php or blade    
        foreach($replies->articles as $article){
           //$article->id   
        }
    */  
    
    return view('tickets.ticket', compact('ticket', 'companies', 'severities', 'replies'));
 }
```

**Blade**

```
@foreach ($replies as $reply)
    <div class="NjBSH">
        <div id="AuthorAndDate-1">
            <span class="author">{{ $reply->user->name }}</span>
            <span class="date"><span style="color: rgb(32, 33, 36);">{{ $reply->created_at }}</span><br></span>
        </div>
        
        <div class="kmSodw">
            <span>{{ $reply->text }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: wont `$reply->user` be null unless you have `with('user')` in the query?

Comment: look my controller I dont have defined $ticketId or $userId

Comment: @BagusTesa If you call the Model directly, you can search the columns without loading, its not a good approach, so based on this I added 2 more options for him, thank you very much!

Comment: @BIGH I'm giving you a design approach, please read the code rather than copy-pasting it and adjust it accordingly, also see the other options you can use to better design your software.

Comment: @KGG See my Full controller please

Comment: @BIGH perfect, I will re-write the controller for you give me a second

Comment: @KGG at least the first `$replies` will need to use `$reply->user()->name`. its a (very) lazy load that will invoke query upon `User`'s table on every `for` iterations. the other 2 options are fine.

Comment: @BIGH does the ticket have a user_id or is the user_id only inside of the reply model?

Comment: no. user_id I have in database in reply table

Comment: @BIGH check the modified solution, please take a moment to read the controller changes, it might be hard to follow at first, but this is the standard practice for high quality relationships handling, I will be on standby to help you further, but you need to create a relationship for reply model to have user(), we mainly do things this way to **avoid N+1 issues** https://laravel-news.com/laravel-n1-query-problems

Comment: @BIGH it would be nice if you accepted this answer, since you used it to complete your question